# WIX: writing a permanent registry key but erase the value when uninstalling

Tags: installation, wix, registry, uninstallation

I have such a scenario for our installer project using WIX 3.6: we want to create a registry key in the installation(if this one does not already exist), write a string value with version number. In the uninstallation, we would like to keep this registry key, but erase this string value to empty string. I know I can achieve the "keeping registry key" part by setting it as "Permanent", but I don't know how to make the uninstallation erase the value. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Uninstall should automatically remove the value it wrote during installation. Wouldn't it be enough?

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov Like I mentioned, I'd like to keep the registry key I created in the installation, mainly for re-installation in the future, that's why I marked it as "Permanent". And I confirmed that by setting "Permanent" the key will be kept after uninstallation. On the other hand, I'd like to erase the string value (I want to be sure that I make it clear, a value is a string or DWORD or whatever you add to the registry key. And a key can have multiple values or sub-keys). So keeping the registry key but erasing the value is what I want

Comment: have you tried to set the Action attribute of your key to "none" and then nest the RegistryValue in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I mentioned on the comment of caveman_dick's answer, I had to add a custom action to do the work. Could't find a way of configuring WIX to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure this will work as I haven't done it myself, but might be worth a go.

Firstly create the key with the ForceCreateOnInstall (Permanent shouldn't be required) this will not remove the key on uninstall:

```
<Component Id="RegistryEntryKey" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKCU"
                 Key="Software\Microsoft\MyApplicationName"
                 ForceCreateOnInstall="yes">
        <RegistryValue Type="integer" 
                       Name="VersionNumber"                            
                       KeyPath="yes"/>
    </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

then just have a second compoment that just writes the version on installation:

```
<Component Id="RegistryEntryValue" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKCU"
                 Key="Software\Microsoft\MyApplicationName"
                 Action="write">
        <RegistryValue Type="integer" 
                       Name="VersionNumber" 
                       Value="1.2.35" 
                       KeyPath="yes"/>
    </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

That should then just undo the write when you un-install.

Comment: It doesn't really work. But I shall follow your lead to find a solution. The problems with your code is 1) in WIX 3.6 the "Action" attribute of RegistryKey is deprecated, but adding it wouldn't cause any error, just not the desired result 2) it is actually not allowed to have a RegistryValue without a value attribute, this will throw an error 3) for the first component, even if I add an empty string as Value(hoping this empty string will be restored after uninstallation), the whole registry key is actually removed during uninstallation. I guess WIX just changed a lot of its behavior

Comment: Oh well! :) I suppose the other option, if the built in stuff won't do what you want, is to create a CustomAction to do it yourself. Not ideal but actually not that difficult with a managed custom action.

Comment: that's exactly what I am doing. I try to avoid custom action as much as I can but this is the situation that I have to do it